# How change glob in one function to see it in another function?

Tags: google-apps-script

English is not my native language, big sorry for my mistakes

Here is my real problem

```
var k = 2;
var m;

function onOpen(){ // on event - Open spreadsheet
    m = 5;
}

function onEdit(){ // on event - Edit spreadsheet
    var n = k; // k = 2
    var p = m; // p = undefine (why?)
}
```

- Why p is undefined?
- Why is `m` in function `onEdit` != 5?
- How can I change `m` in function `onOpen` and then make `p` = `m` (= 5)?

Answer (score 0):

> - Why p is undefined?
> - Why is m in function onEdit != 5?

The GAS internals instances and initializes the code every time a function is called, i.e. the `onOpen` function is called during a spreadsheet is opened, GAS instances the code, the `m` variable is equal to 5. After that the `onEdit` function is called and the GAS creates a new instance of the code, in this instance the `onOpen` function is **not** called and the `m` variable is equal to `undefined` by default and this value is assigned to the `p`.

> - How can I change m in function onOpen and then make p = m (= 5)?

To achieve it, you have to use intermediate services like the [Cache](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_cacheservice) or the [ScriptDB](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_scriptdb) Services.