# How to Access ScriptDB from Spreadsheet Custom Function?

Tags: google-apps-script

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969813/), I suggested to use the `ScriptDB` as an intermediate storage for global data of a [Container Extension](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_extensions) code. I wrote a sample code for my answer but the sample throws the `error: You do not have permission to call query (line X)` exception in a `ScriptDb.getMyDb().query(...);` line. I created the following simpler example demonstrating the problem. The code, both `getDBSize` and `getSource` functions, is permitted to use the `ScriptDB` by running it in the editor. The `getDBSize` function is executed without any problem by pressing the `Run` button in the Spreadsheet `Script Manager` Dialog. The `getSource` function works everywhere.

I published the Spreadsheet for the example - [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsDEe8rhzR17dGhaUDlqekVEdEdVdzA5eUhSQmFrb1E). It is impossible to share the code for view, but it is possible to output it in a cell, the cell `B3` contains exactly bellow code.

How is possible to permit the Spreadsheet Code to have access to the `ScriptDB`?

```
function getDBSize() {
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb(); 
  var result = db.query({});  
  var count = result.getSize();
  return count;
}

function getSource() {
  return this.toSource();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to run this function as a spreadsheet `custom function`, and custom functions are way more limited than all examples on the [Container Extension](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_extensions) page you linked.

But, from a theoretical point of view, custom functions as well as simple event handlers (e.g. `onEdit`, `onOpen`), can not access anything that requires the user account or is associated with the user, only "generic" methods. For example, `UrlFetchApp`, open the current spreadsheet, or read `ScriptProperties`.

So, in thesis, querying a `ScriptDb` should be possible, since it's a generic call and has nothing to do with the active user, it's analogous to `ScriptProperties`. I don't see a workaround that would actually let you query the db, but you could use `ScriptProperties` instead. You can easily save and retrieve any object you would save on `ScriptDb` by using `JSON.stringify` and `.parse`. Of course, I'm not comparing `ScriptDb` capabilites with `ScriptProperties`, it's just a workaround.

Anyway, this seems like a good candidate for an enhancement request on our [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).